# Break from imbricated for loop

Tags: bash, shell, ash

I want to know if there is a way to leave imbricated for loop:

```
check_mac_address() {
    local mac="$1"
    for wunit in `get_wunit`; do
        for iuc in `get_iuc`; do            
            for assoc_mac in `get_iuc $wunit $iuc`;do
                if [ "$assoc_mac" = "$mac"]; then 
                    local int_type="WF" 
                    break #---> break from all loop  
                else
                    int_type="ETH"
                    break #---> break from all loop  
                fi 
            done
        done
    done
}
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: TIL: "imbricated" is a word. "Nested" is the usual term used for this construct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break` takes a parameter which specifies how many levels of surrounding loops to break; in your case I believe it would be 3:

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins

Answer (score 2):

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loopcontrol.html

> A plain break terminates only the innermost loop in which it is embedded, but a break N breaks out of N levels of loop.

So in your case you to break from all three loops you can do

```
break 3
```

Comment: A link to the bash reference manual or the appropriate POSIX specification is much more useful than one to the TLDP bash guide.